# ActionBar menu icon not showing

Tags: android, xml

There is an app for API21+ (Material Design).

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    <application
       ...
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

**styles.xml**:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

**menu_item_add.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_save"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add_entry"
        android:title="@string/action_add"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Menu is inflated inside `Activity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_item_add, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Android Studio preview show, that it supposed to look like:

[image]

But the "Add" is hidden, the menu item is shown along with "Settings" inside popup.

**Question**:

- How to make sure the icon is shown?

**EDIT**:

It seems my problem is similar to this one:

[app:showAsAction vs android:showAsAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26412474/appshowasaction-vs-androidshowasaction)

However my `Activity` looks like:

```
...
public class EntryAddActivity extends Activity {
...
```

So I don't understand why am I getting message about appcompat.

Comment: Do you see what you expect to see when you run the app?

Comment: No, the icon is hidden. The "Add" menu item is positioned along with "Settings" inside popup.

Comment: Change the namespace prefix on `showAsAction` to `android`.

Comment: So you do not want it to be present there at all?

Comment: @MikeM. it seems the solution is to switch to `android:` namespace. However I've got the message related to `appcompat`. Should I use `Toolbar` instead of `ActionBar` to get rid of `appcompat`?

Comment: I don't know what message you mean, but if you're using `Theme.Material`, you can't use any (maybe just most?) appcompat `View`s with it.

Comment: @MikeM. I was able to resolve my problem by using `android:` namespace. If you add your answer, I will mark it as solution.

Comment: Well, that post you just added to your question has the answer, and it's the one I use for duplicates, so I'll just mark this as a duplicate. Thanks, though. Appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!