# action bar shows up the list instead of buttons

Tags: android

I have an action bar on the app which looks like this:

[image]

Now i am pretty sure , i don't have a default theme on the app but what i was hoping to get buttons instead of the list.Something of this sort.

[image]

```
 <menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_shuffle"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_shuffle_black_18dp"
        android:title="Shuffle"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:checked="false"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_end"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_close_black_18dp"
        android:title="End"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

I have `showasaction` set to `always`, it still shows it up as a list.

Manifest looks something like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tilak.imusicplay">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/playicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:name="com.example.tilak.imusicplay.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.example.tilak.imusicplay.MusicService" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Am i missing out something? why doesn't it show up the buttons instead? Like i see in my preview?

Update:

whole code can be uploaded if there is a need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Item with app:showAsAction not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26377305/item-with-appshowasaction-not-showing)

Answer (score 0):

You should set it to

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

Or you must set your theme to AppCompat
Check out this
[Item with app:showAsAction not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26377305/item-with-appshowasaction-not-showing)