# Tablayout Title doesn't appear

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a Tablayout to show three fragments via ViewPager and adapter, the problem is that the titles doesn't appear:
MainActivity.java:

```
package com.asd.tab3;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TabLayout tb;
ViewPager vp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tb=findViewById(R.id.tab1);
        vp=findViewById(R.id.viwp);
        final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this,getSupportFragmentManager(), tb.getTabCount());
        vp.setAdapter(adapter);
       tb.setupWithViewPager(vp);
    }

}
```

MyAdapter.java

```
package com.asd.tab3;
import android.content.Context;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private Context myContext;
    int totalTabs;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm, int totalTabs) {
        super(fm);
        myContext = context;
        this.totalTabs = totalTabs;
    }

    // this is for fragment tabs
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                BlankFragment homeFragment = new BlankFragment();
                return homeFragment;
            case 1:
                BlankFragment2 sportFragment = new BlankFragment2();
                return sportFragment;
            case 2:
                BlankFragment3 movieFragment = new BlankFragment3();
                return movieFragment;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
    // this counts total number of tabs
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return totalTabs;
    }
}
```

Rem: my problem is different from this post: ([Titles in TabLayout donsen't appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50424094/titles-in-tablayout-donsent-appear))

Comment: public int getCount() {
        return totalTabs.size();
    }

Answer (score 0):

You should override method `getPageTitle()` inside your `FragmentPageAdapter` class (`MyAdapter` in your case).

```
 * This method may be called by the ViewPager to obtain a title string
 * to describe the specified page. This method may return null
 * indicating no title for this page. The default implementation returns
 * null.
 *
 * @param position The position of the title requested
 * @return A title for the requested page

  fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence?
```

Currently, title does not appear because it's using default implementation of the method, that always returns null.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using (getTabAt(index).setText = "Some Text";)

```
 tb.getTabAt(0).setText("First");
```